# Field expression not allowed for generic SObject on Trigger

Tags: trigger

im writing a trigger for AfterUpdate on contact:

```
private void mergeSlaveToMaster(){
    for(Contact c: Trigger.new){
        try
        {
            if(c.Merge_With__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.id).Merge_With__c)
            {
                Id masterId = [SELECT Merge_With__r.Id from Contact where id=:c.Merge_With__c][0].Id;
                Contact masterContact = [SELECT ID from Contact where id=:masterId];

                merge masterContact c;
            }
        }
        catch (DmlException e)
        {
            System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

i receive an error on the line:

```
if(c.Merge_With__c != Trigger.oldMap.get(c.id).Merge_With__c)
```

the error is:

> Save Error: Field expression not allowed for generic SObject

i didnt find a suitable answer online, quite new to salesforce. please advise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

trigger context variable are sobject type, you have to convert it into specific object like

```
map<Id, Contact> mapOldContact = Trigger.oldMap;
```

and now this variable

```
if(c.Merge_With__c != mapOldContact.get(c.id).Merge_With__c)
```

Comment: i also needed to add `for(Contact c: (List<Contact>) Trigger.new){` and then it worked. Thanks!

Comment: It's worth noting that this only really seems to apply to situations where you're using trigger context variables outside of a trigger. Inside of a trigger, Salesforce has enough context to determine the concrete SObject type, and you'll have no problems using something like `Trigger.oldMap.get(c.Id).Merge_With__c` without casting.